# How to insert 2d control in the wpf 3d cube

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have created one 3d cube using Viewport3D in WPF.I have created 6 GeometryModel3D inside Viewport since I want to show the differnt contents on each face.I want to insert one userinteractice buttone control on one of the face(front face) of cube.I know we should use Viewport2DVisual3D for this purpose.But I am not able to find a solution how I can insert the 2ndd control on the face using Viewport2DVisual3D.Please help me .Below is my Xamal code I have written sofar:

```
<Grid>
        <Viewport3D>
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera Position="0,0,25" LookDirection="15,6,-50" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>

            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <!--<AmbientLight Color="White" />-->
                    <SpotLight Color="White" InnerConeAngle="20" OuterConeAngle="60" Direction="15,6,-50" Position="0,0,25" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>

            <ModelVisual3D>

                <ModelVisual3D.Content>

                    <Model3DGroup>


                                <!-- front -->
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D
                                Positions="0 0 0, 10 0 0, 0 16 0, 10 16 0, 10 0 0"
                                TriangleIndices="0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3"
                                TextureCoordinates="0 1, 1 1, 0 0, 1 0, 1 1"
                                />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Brush="White"/>

                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>

                            <Viewport2DVisual3D>

                                <StackPanel>   
                                <Button>Hello, 3D</Button>
                                 </StackPanel>
                            </Viewport2DVisual3D>

                        </GeometryModel3D>


                        <!-- left -->
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D
                            Positions="0 0 -.5, 0 0 0, 0 14 -.5, 0 14 0, 0 0 0"
                            TriangleIndices="0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <MaterialGroup>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{StaticResource side}" />
                                </MaterialGroup>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Color="Blue" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D>

                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D
                            Positions="0 14 -4, 0 14 0, 0 16 -4, 0 16 0, 0 14 0"
                            TriangleIndices="0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <MaterialGroup>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{StaticResource top}" />
                                </MaterialGroup>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Color="Blue" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D>

                        <!-- right  -->
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D
                            Positions="10 0 0, 10 0 -.5, 10 16 0, 10 16 -.5, 10 0 -.5"
                            TriangleIndices="0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <MaterialGroup>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{StaticResource top}" />
                                </MaterialGroup>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Color="Blue" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D>


                        <!-- top side -->
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D
                            Positions="0 16 0, 0 16 -.5, 10 16 0, 10 16 -.5, 0 16 -.5"
                            TriangleIndices="0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4"
                                TextureCoordinates="0 1, 0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0"
                                />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <MaterialGroup>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{StaticResource pages}" />
                                </MaterialGroup>

                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Color="Blue" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D>

                        <!-- bottom -->
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D
                            Positions="0 0 0, 0 0 -.5, 10 0 0, 10 0 -.5, 0 0 -.5"
                            TriangleIndices="0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3"
                                TextureCoordinates="0 1, 0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0"
                                />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{StaticResource pages}" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Color="Blue" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D>

                        <!-- back -->
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D
                            Positions="0 0 -.5, 10 0 -.5, 0 16 -.5, 10 16 -.5, 10 0 -.5"
                            TriangleIndices="0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <MaterialGroup>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{StaticResource back}" />
                                </MaterialGroup>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Color="Blue" />
                            </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D>




                    </Model3DGroup>

                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>

        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a couple of things wrong here. The Viewport2DVisual3D doesn't go inside a GeometryModel3D, it replaces it. This also means that you have to pull it outside the Model3DGroup. Finally, you need to set `Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial` so that WPF knows to use the brush for the 2D elements as well. This should be enough to get you started:

```
<Grid>
    <Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="-10,0,50" LookDirection="15,10,-50" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <!--<AmbientLight Color="White" />-->
                <SpotLight Color="White" InnerConeAngle="20" OuterConeAngle="60" Direction="15,6,-50" Position="0,0,25" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>


        <!-- front -->
        <Viewport2DVisual3D>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D
                            Positions="0 0 0, 10 0 0, 0 16 0, 10 16 0, 10 0 0"
                            TriangleIndices="0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3"
                            TextureCoordinates="0 1, 1 1, 0 0, 1 0, 1 1"
                            />
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

            <StackPanel>
                <Button>Hello, 3D</Button>
            </StackPanel>

        </Viewport2DVisual3D>

    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you...but I want this button on the  cube surface  so that  whenever user rotate the cube this button will be stick to the cube surface and rotate